# Jest tests execute before setState has had a chance to render from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have really struggled trying to get my tests to wait until my component has finished rendering before executing. I'm not sure if I have my component set up in a way that isn't conducive to testing or if I need some other tool like sinon.

I know that axios-mock-adapter is working because I can log out the response in componentDidMount and see the mocked data but the logs for the response always come after the console logs I have in the tests. I tried taking snapshots too and I can see that the divs are not being rendered.

I have recreated the problem using create-react-app and tried to make it as simple as possible, hoping someone can help me get past this...

My container:

```
import React from "react";
import { getUsersApi } from "./api";
import UserList from "./UserList";

type Props = {
  /* */
};

class UserListContainer extends React.Component<Props> {
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const response = await getUsersApi();
      if (response && response.data) {
        console.log("response.data", response.data);
        //when testing I get the fake data
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <UserList users={this.state.users} />;
  }
}

export default UserListContainer;
```

The list:

```
import React from "react";

const UserList = props => (
  <main>
    {props.users
      ? props.users.map(user => {
          return (
            <div className="user-item" key={user.id}>
              {user.name}
            </div>
          );
        })
      : ""}
  </main>
);

export default UserList;
```

The api call:

```
import axios from "axios";

export function getUsersApi() {
  return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
}
```

And my test:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
import { configure, mount } from "enzyme";
import UserListContainer from "./UserListContainer";
// setup file
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

// This sets the mock adapter on the default instance
let mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Fake User 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Fake User 2"
  }
];

mock.onGet("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").reply(200, users);

describe("UserListContainer", async () => {
  it("gets successful response from API", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<UserListContainer />);
    console.log(wrapper.update().state("users").length); //returns 0
    console.log(wrapper.find(".user-wrapper").length); //returns 0
    expect(wrapper.find("main").length).toBeGreaterThan(0); //passes
  });
});
```

My test returns:

```
 PASS  src\UserListContainer.test.js
  UserListContainer
    √ gets successful response from API (8ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.813s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites.

  console.error node_modules\fbjs\lib\warning.js:33
    Warning: React depends on requestAnimationFrame. Make sure that you load a polyfill in older browsers. http://fb.
me/react-polyfills

  console.log src\UserListContainer.test.js:29
    0

  console.log src\UserListContainer.test.js:30
    0

  console.log src\UserListContainer.js:14
    response.data [ { id: 1, name: 'Fake User 1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Fake User 2' } ]
```

So the component isn't rendering the divs that have the names even though the response is clearly being mocked. I tried the update function (in the first console log) but I think that may just be for shallow render? I have also tried moxios with the same result. Thanks